# Check if input is all caps and numbers

Tags: python, validation

I need to check if my input is all caps and numbers, it must also contain "A1" and be a multiple of 4.

```
def valid_product_code(string):

    #A1 must be in string
    if "A1" in string:
        val = True

    #String must be a multiple of 4
    if len(string) % 4 == 0:
        val = True

    #Must only have capitals or numbers
    if (char.isdigit() or char.islower() for char in string):
        val=True

    else:
        val = False

    return val
```

What am I doing wrong? When I test it, it only returns True

Comment: What's the problem ? What result to you have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **all** keyword so it will check all of the characters, change the **islower** to **isupper** and you override the return value

```
def valid_product_code(string):

    #A1 must be in string
    if "A1" not in string:
        return False

    #String must be a multiple of 4
    if len(string) % 4 != 0:
        return False

    #Must only have capitals or numbers
    if not all(char.isdigit() or char.isupper() for char in string):
        return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out, it uses some regex to check and make sure all letters are capitalized

```
import re


def valid_product_code(string):

    # Regex pattern to check for all caps
    pattern = '^[A-Z0-9]*$'

    # Validation
    valid = False

    # Check for all caps
    if re.search(pattern, string):
        # Check for A1
        if "A1" in string:
            # Check for multiple of 4
            if len(string) % 4 == 0:
                valid = True

    return valid
```

Regex is a great use case for something like this. You could also modify your function to automatically convert the string to upper case with string.upper(). Then you can return the capitalize string along with validation check with  return string, valid. This would eliminate the need to check for capital letters all together.